What does להדיאש mean?
In the sefer על הגאולה ועל התמורה, in the middle of the פרקי פתיחה. It's written:

ונהירא שבאמצע המערכה נגד גזירת הבריכה בשנת תשי"ח ונאסר אז עליו הדיבור מצד הרופאים, והציעו לפניו מטעם איזה רבנים שנטו לשיטת המתחברים, שבמקום המחאה יפרסמו קול קורא בצורת מודעה שפעולותיהם הם נגד התורה וזה יועיל, כותב רבינו דעתו: ...
אמנם אם כותבים קול קורא לפרסם בעולם, צריך שיהיה בו איזה הערה מה מבקשים מהעולם, כי זה וודאי להודיע להעולם גנות המדינה זה וודאי לא ירצו, גם אין לו פירוש לפי דעת ההמון, ואי אפשר שיהיה איזה יסוד כל שהוא להקו"ק אלא אם יש בו ההערה להנותני כסף שישתדלו בזה, והוא נוגע להדיאש [-הדזשואיש] אפיל, וזה בודאי לא ירצו כבר.

What is the translation of להדיאש?

דזשואיש sound like "Jewish". Can you include more context?

Sounds like he's transliterating "Jewish Appeal." Might very well be the Yiddish acronym for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Jewish_Appeal

It’s the United Jewish appeal. “Jewish” written in Hebrew and then transliterated into Yiddish. See page 21 of this pdf: https://yiddishevinkel.com/archives/weekly_newsletters/%D7%90%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%94-%D7%95%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%AA?download

דיאש is jewish in hebrew?

@Shababnik the typical transliteration for a "J" sound is Dalet-Zayin, or Dalet-Zayin-Shin. I suspect he's purposely treating the name as non-Hebrew here because he doesn't feel it's truly Jewish. (For instance, the Igros Moshe uses the Hebrew "rav" for Orthodox clergy, but transliterates "rabbi" for Reform ones.)

@Shalom I understand the word in brackets. What I'm asking is for the meaning of הדיאש

That's the point. He's deliberately messing with the pronunciation, calling it the "Deish Appeal" because he doesn't feel it's very Jewish. Then the brackets are telling you to pronounce it as "Jewish."
